Refreshing minicart on parent page from within fancybox Iframe on HTML page. No woocommerce or wp
I have a site with a iframe html page pop up in fancybox. When items are added or taken away from the cart in the iframe, the items are added in the iframe page but when I close the iframe, the parent page still has the same amount and is not updating. Ive tried a little bit of everything so I wound up just refreshing the parent page every time fancybox closes.
Is there a way  to refresh just the minicart on the parent page without it refreshing the whole page every time because they lose their place on the page and it just looks bad.
I see solutions here for woocommerce and wordpress but not just for regular pages.
This looks similar to other questions but ive tried all of those solutions and they dont work.

You could, for example, reload parent page when closing Fancybox modal. Add close event listener where you would do smth like window.parent.location.reload();.

That is exactly what I am doing now. The problem with that is that I have a filter on the page so for example if they click "butterfly paintings", only those show up. When the parent page reloads, they loose their place because the filter resets. Also it doesnt look too good to keep refreshing after each look at paintings. I was hoping to just reset the minicart and not the whole page but perhaps theres no way to do it?

Then you should check the minicart docs or ask a question specifically about refreshing the minicart.

I did. That was my question: "s there a way to refresh just the minicart on the parent page without it refreshing the whole page every time because they lose their place on the page and it just looks bad. "

Make it simpler like "How to refresh minicart" because now your question is confusing, it includes "fancybox" but it's not relevant.

I couldnt remove it because fancybox iframe is relevant and it is exactly what I need. As explained, from inside the fancybox iframe, I needed to somehow refresh the minicart on the parent page as it was not updating when the cart inside the fancybox iframe was updating. I was able to figure it out for the most part.

It makes absolutely no difference whether you execute the code from the fancybox iframe or not. The only difference would be to include parent, e.g.,  window.parent.something() or window.something(). You just have to figure out that is something() :)
